# Find a run of five or more consecutive zeros in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

This is the code that I had tried to find the consecutive zero which are in the order of 5 or more.

```
a=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,8,5,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,4,6,8,0,0,9,8,4,0,0,7,8,9,5,0,0,0,0,0,8,9,0,5,8,7,0,0,0,0,0];

[x,y]=size(a);

for i=0:y
 i+1;
 k=1;
 l=0;
 n=i;
 count=0;

while (a==0)
 count+1;
 break;  
 n+1;
end
if(count>=5)
 v([]);
for l=k:l<n
 v(m)=l+1;
 m+1;
 end    
end    
count=1;
i=n;
end    
for i = o : i<m
i+1;

fprintf('index of continous zero more than 5 or equal=%d',v(i));

end
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to find the starting indices of runs of `n` or more zeros:

```
v = find(conv(double(a==0),ones(1,n),'valid')==n); %// find n zeros
v = v([true diff(v)>n]); %// remove similar indices, indicating n+1, n+2... zeros
```

In your example, this gives

```
v =
     1    13    34    45
```

Comment: what to do if we want to find the middle zero index instead of starting zero index, i.e. v = 4 16 and so on

Comment: @FarazAhmad Use `v+(n+1)/2`?

Answer (score 1):

One-liner `strfind` approach to find the starting indices of `5` consecutive zeros -

```
out = strfind(['0' num2str(a==0,'%1d')],'011111')
```

Output -

```
out =

     1    13    34    45
```

The above code could be generalised like this -

```
n = 5 %// number of consecutive matches
match = 0 %// match to be used
out = strfind(['0' num2str(a==match,'%1d')],['0' repmat('1',1,n)]) %// starting indices of n consecutive matches
```

If you are looking to find all the indices where the `n` consecutive matches were found, you can add this code -

```
outb = strfind([num2str(a==match,'%1d'),'0'],[repmat('1',1,n) '0'])+n-1
allind = find(any(bsxfun(@ge,1:numel(a),out') & bsxfun(@le,1:numel(a),outb')))
```

Comment: Two very elegant things here. 1) you put the "sentinel `0`" in front of the string so you can find just the beginning of a run; and 2) using `a==0` converts the number into a boolean array (so it's easy to convert this to any other condition). But you have a typo - in second example, `num2str(a==0` should be `num2str(a==match`.

Comment: @Floris Thanks for the bug find! Fixed! Yes the basic idea is to use sort of like a step function that slides across it thanks to `strfind`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the general case of a "run of n or more values x in vector V", you could do the following:

```
% your particular case:
n = 5;
x = 0;
V = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,8,5,6,0,0,0,0, ...
     0,0,3,4,6,8,0,0,9,8,4,0,0,7,8,9, ...
     5,0,0,0,0,0,8,9,0,5,8,7,0,0,0,0,0];


b = (V == x); % create boolean array: ones and zeros
d = diff( [0 b 0] );  % turn the start and end of a run into +1 and -1
startRun = find( d==1 );
endRun = find( d==-1 );
runlength = endRun - startRun;
answer = find(runlength > n);
runs = runlength(answer);
disp([answer(:) runs(:)]);
```

This will display the start of the run, and its length, for all runs > n of value x.